# Compare CurrentThread from ProcessThread.Id

Tags: .net, multithreading

How can I check if `CurrentThread` is the one specified by `ProcessThread.Id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET stops you from assuming that a Thread is actually an operating system thread.  It is on any shipping version of the CLR but that was not originally the plan.  A project in the SQL Server team to implement Thread on top of a fiber failed.  You'll have to pinvoke GetCurrentThreadId().  Visit pinvoke.net for the declaration.